# How to filter out non pet friendly places in google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

- **goal** I am trying to use `places_nearby` api to get the nearby pet-friendly hotels or restaurants. How can I do that? with google places

```
import googlemaps
from django.conf import settings
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=settings.PLACES_MAPS_API_KEY)
search = gmaps.places_nearby((float(lat), float(lng)), name=type, radius=float(radius))
```

---

- **Note**: `googlemaps` is just package that make my life easier and this api is check the following alternative

```
import requests

url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522%2C151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: You can file a FR for this matter in Google Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309

Answer (score 1):

Pet-friendliness is not an attribute currently offered for Places API Nearby Search (see [supported parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby)).